# Connect to voip channel from server and record

Tags: twilio, sip, voip

I have a conferencing set via Twilio, which supports recording out of the box. However, I can't use their recording service due to privacy issues (HIPAA). So I thought perhaps standing up a server under my control which could connect to the conference room and record the audio stream.

1. What tools/platforms are there to connect to a Twilio voip channel in an unattended fashion?
2. I could have Twilio dial out and connect the conference room to a sip endpoint in a server I stand up - again what tools or platforms could I use for this?
3. Beyond connecting I need to record the stream.

Any insights appreciated!

Comment: Have you checked this documentation on [HIPAA compliance with Twilio](https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/223136467-Ensuring-HIPAA-compliancy-with-Twilio-made-applications)? You can protect recordings with a username and password, for example.

Comment: Thanks @philnash. That would be inadequate. For HIPAA compliance, Twilio would have to execute a BAA (they wont) and the file would have to be stored using encryption with AES256 or better.